# Webview showing camera popup permission dialogue which is not required to show using UWP, C#

Tags: c#, uwp

I am implementing an application that has **Barcode scanner** for this added webcam permission in capabilities then Barcode scanner working as expected but in the application, it has a login page which is shown in **Webview** when the user trying to login at that time showing the camera permission request popup which is not required to show here(Barcode scanner and login both pages are different). Can you please help me out to resolve this issue?
and is there anyway to give Run permission for camera access.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Is the permission request popup generated by Chromium, or is it a UWP-platform request popup? Please post a screenshot.

Comment: it is platform request popup

Comment: Added screen shot please check.

Comment: Even though the app has Webcam permission, the system will still prompt the user for permission the first time the app requests it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can we give runtime permission just before opening the camera other than mention in capabilities using UWP?

Answer (score 0):

The dialog will appear only when you need to use the related APIs(camera capture). Once permission is granted once that permission will persist until the user retracts it.

And if *showing the camera permission request popup which is not required to show here* you need check if current page has called camera api such as initialize camera

> Can we give runtime permission just before opening the camera other than mention in capabilities using UWP

I'm afraid you can't give runtime permission for opening camera, as Raymond Chen comment above, this is system behavior, and there is no such api could manage it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Camera api related functionalities are not calling in the login page.

Comment: you mentioned the login page is webview, can you check if web page has accessed camera?